# What is the difference between 3 planes meeting at a point versus on a line?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The question is below. The part I need help is in part (b) of the solution that I have posted in the picture. I dont get why the second system of equations with the parameter $s$ (pointed with the arrow) look the way they look? Why is it just the directional vector of the other system of equations multiplied by 2? Could it have been any other number?

I have a feeling this has something to do with the fundamental difference between 3 planes meeting at a point versus a line. Is this correct? Thank you!

Let $a \in \Bbb{R}$ and consider the planes
\begin{align*}
π_1:&& x + ay + 2z &= 1 \\
π_2:&& 2x + (2a + 5)y + 6z &= 2 \\
π_3:&& ax − 6y &= 3 
\end{align*}

(a) For which values of $a$ do the planes intersect at exactly one point?

(b) Determine $a$ so that the planes intersect along a line and determine a parametric
equation of the line of intersection in this case.

Below is the solution to the question.

[image: Solution]

Comment: thank you for the edit @sammy black

Comment: Do you understand the “previous calculation” (not pictured), presumably row reduction to show that in the cases $a \in \{2, 3\}$, the system is equivalent to one with a final equation where all coefficients of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are $0$? This gives either an *inconsistent* system (no solutions) or a *redundant* system (extra equation with no information and a line’s worth of solutions from the other two equations).

Comment: Thank you but I want to know why the equation I have pointed has anything to do with a line of intersection when it was derived for a point of intersection..

Comment: You are looking for ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy the given equations simultaneously. Sometimes there is a unique solution, and other times there are many solutions that lie along a line. A line is just a lot of points!

Comment: Picture the intersection of two walls in a room with the ceiling for an example of a unique point, and picture the `*` symbol extruded, as a pasta maker would, to show an example of three planes intersecting in a line of points.

Comment: Awesome explanation Sammy! That was helpful to visualize. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the equation in the middle column, we have $2z=-5t$, which is equivalent to $z=-\frac{5t}{2}$. Some might not like fractional coefficient and prefer integer coefficient and hence they did a transformation of $t=2s$.

Hence we obtain $z=-\frac{5(2s)}{s}=-5s$.

$x=2(2s)+1=4s+1$ and $y=t=2s$.

Comment: So technically, I could have just kept it as $ z = \frac{-5t}{2} $ ? Is this variable change only because of not liking fractions?

Comment: My second question is, isnt this then the parametric equation for 3 planes meeting at a single point? What does it have to do with 3 planes meeting on a line? Because the case $a=3$ is for 3 planes meeting at a single point right?

Comment: You can leave your solution in terms of $t$, and it is correct. How the three planes intersect depends on the value of $a$. In part $a$, the question is for which value of $a$, the plane intersects at a point, the answer is as long as $a$ is not equal to $2$ or $3$. For part $b$, they ask a separate question, which value of $a$, it intersects at a line, find the line. For $a=3$, it intersects at a line, not a point.

Comment: Perfect! I got it thanks to your tip! Thank you so much! <3